# Getting variable from Mysql with a Loop on MPDF

Tags: php, mysql, mpdf

I am trying to write something from the database in a MPDF file. I need to make a loop, but i can't do it inside the "WriteHTML" part, because it won't recognize as PHP code. 
If i print the variable outside the loop, it won't recognize the whole array.

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];

$funcao = $_SESSION['funcao'];
$area = $_SESSION['area'];
$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
$apelido = $_SESSION['apelido'];
$chefe = $_SESSION['chefe'];
include 'includes/connect.php';
$id = $_SESSION['id'];


include "mpdf/mpdf.php";
```

Here is the loop:

```
    $pc=mysql_query("SELECT * from pp where id_user=$id" );
    $row = array();
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($pc)) $row[] = $data; 
        foreach ($row as $x){
        $id_producto = $x[0];
        $nome = $x[1];
        $preco = $x[2];
        $descricao = $x[3];
}
```

And the rest...

```
$html="
<center><img src='imagens/logo.png' width='100' height='100'></center>
<center><h3>Curriculo</h3></center>
Nome: $nome $apelido <br>
E-Mail: $email <bR>
Função: $funcao <br>
Área: $area <br>
Chefia: $chefe <br>


<h1>titulo</h1>
";


$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your loop:

```
    $pc=mysql_query("SELECT * from pp where id_user=$id" );
    $row = array();
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($pc)) $row[] = $data; 
        foreach ($row as $x){
        $id_producto = $x[0];
        $nome = $x[1];
        $preco = $x[2];
        $descricao = $x[3];
}
```

All you have to do is add your **$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);**

```
<?php

$html="
<center><img src='imagens/logo.png' width='100' height='100'></center>
<center><h3>Curriculo</h3></center>
Nome: $nome $apelido <br>
E-Mail: $email <bR>
Função: $funcao <br>
Área: $area <br>
Chefia: $chefe <br>


<h1>titulo</h1>
";

$mpdf=new mPDF(); // Start the mPDF document
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // Write out your initial HTML portion

        // Query to get the information you want
        $pc=mysql_query("SELECT * from pp where id_user=$id" );
        $row = array();
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($pc)) $row[] = $data; 
            foreach ($row as $x){
            $id_producto = $x[0];
            $nome = $x[1];
            $preco = $x[2];
            $descricao = $x[3];
        // Inside the loop you add new HTML lines to be written to the PDF
        // You can format this with normal HTML and output the data to the PDF
        // You should work with this section on your own to format it how you want
            $mpdf->WriteHTML("Producto: $id_producto");
            $mpdf->WriteHTML("Nome: $nome");
    }

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way to

```
$values='';


foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
$values .='<br>product name'.$condition['nome'].'<br>';
 $values .=<br>product id'.$condition['id_product'].'<br>';
}
$html="<center><img src='imagens/logo.png' width='100' height='100'>
</center>
<center><h3>Curriculo</h3></center>
Nome: $nome $apelido <br>
E-Mail: $email <bR>
Função: $funcao <br>
Área: $area <br>
Chefia: $chefe <br>
<h1>titulo</h1>
$values ";
$mpdf=new mPDF(); // Start the mPDF document
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // Write out your initial HTML portion
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```